# Passing specific data on partials using Ajax in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm new to rails and what I'm trying to do is the following:

I'm creating a store and unstore button to save and 'un-save' the event respectively. I used my event attributes and current user to find that stored event. By using ajax and remote functionality of rails I will able to change the behavior of the button from store to unstore or vise versa.

In my **_feed.html.erb**.

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ul>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Each @feed_items contains set of data (title, category, etc).

In my **_feed_item.html.erb**.

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>" class="item">
    ...
    <div class="small-3 text-center columns">        
      <%= render 'shared/store_form', event: feed_item %>
    </div>
    ...
</li>
```

Event symbol sends that feed_item to the store_form.

In my **_store_form.html.erb**.

```
<div id="store_form_<%= event.id %>">
    <% if event.stored?(current_user) %>
        <%= render 'shared/unstore', event: event %>
    <% else %>
        <%= render 'shared/store', event: event %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I pass again a feed_item into partial.

**_store.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(event.storages.build(saver_id: current_user.id, 
                        organizer_id: event.user_id),
                        remote: true) do |f| %>
    <div>
        <%= f.hidden_field :organizer_id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :saved_id, value: event.id %>
    </div>
  <%= f.submit "store" %>
<% end %>
```

**_unstore.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(event.storages.find_by(saver_id: current_user.id,
                         organizer_id: event.user_id) ,
             html: { method: :delete },
             remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit 'unstore' %>
<% end %>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#store_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/store', event: event )%>")
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$("#store_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/unstore', event: event) %>")
```

And I'm getting these errors when clicking store/unstore event.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `event' for #<#<Class:0x00000004d69be8>:0x00000004d68d10>):
    1: $("#store_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/unstore', event: event) %>")


ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `event' for #<#<Class:0x00000004d69be8>:0x00000004fdc6a0>):
    1: $("#store_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/store', event: event )%>")
```

My question is, how can I pass that specific "event" data into the partial. I can't used @feed_item onto the create and destroy js because feed_item have the set of events. Is there any better approach to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

In your action create and delete in the controller you should instantiate your variable event: change event by @event and change your js to:

```
$("#store_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/unstore') %>
```

because you don´t need add instantiate vars to render calls, rails is doing for you

Comment: I'll try this one. I'll reply if it still not working. But my partial on store and unstore needs to display each of event status coming from set of events.